# Zookeeper Overall data size limit

Tags: apache-zookeeper, hierarchical

I am new to Zookeeper, trying to understand if it fits for my use case.

I have 10 million hierarchical data, which I want to store in Zookeeper.

10M key-value pair with size of the key and value will be 1KB each.

So the total data size is approximately ~20GB (10M * 2KB) without replication.

I know the zNodes data size limit is 1MB( which can be changed).

Questions:

1. Will zookeeper able to support 20GB of data, with no performance impact.
2. Is there max size after which the performance degrades?
3. Is there a limit to total number of nodes?

Answer (score 3):

Zookeeper will no way be suitable for this use case. Zookeeper keeps dumping/snapshotting the data tree periodically and that means it will be dumping whole of the 20 GB data every few minutes. Moreover Zookeeper nodes in the cluster/ensemble are more like replica of each other and hence whole data is replicated to each Zookeeper node and hence no data partitioning either. Zookeeper is not a database.

I guess for your use case, it will be much better to go with some database or some distributed cache (Redis/Hazelcast etc.) 
Anyway there are no limits on the total number of nodes on Zookeeper.

Comment: Are there any docs or guidelines on what the upper limit of the Zookeeper dataset size is?